# Webscraper in Python - How do I extract exact text I need?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Good day

I am trying to write my first webscraper. I have managed to write the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()

r = s.get("http://www.sharenet.co.za/v3/quickshare.php?scode=BTI")

r = s.post("http://www.sharenet.co.za/v3/quickshare.php?scode=BTI")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.find_all("td", class_="dataCell"))
```

I am trying to extract a share price. When Inspect the element this is the HTML code:

```
<td class="dataCell" align="right">85221</td>
```

[Image of share price table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi8e1.png)

Basically, my issue is that can search for all the tags but can't extract the exact tag I want.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is being printed, and what did you expect to be printed?

Comment: I just wanted to get the share price of 85221

Comment: The main point of my comment is that you didn't say what was being printed, which makes it harder to see what is wrong. I see you've got an answer now (which you should accept if helpful), but remember to do that next time.

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks for pointing that out. (Only my 2nd post ever :))

Comment: ie. `soup.find_all("td", class_="dataCell")[10].get_text()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags have a `get_text()` method. `find_all` returns a list of tags.

```
for cell_tag in soup.find_all("td"):
    print(cell_tag.get_text())
```